# Is it worth changing the seed periodically when using python random number generation?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

Assuming I am generating 10,000 random numbers using `random.randrange`, would changing the seed part way through the generation loop have any meaningful difference on the distribution of values generated compared to using the same seed for all 10,000 random numbers?

```
import random 

epoch = int(0)

while True:
    if epoch%100 == 0: #every 100 epochs, generate a new seed
        random.seed()  
    random.randrange(1,1000,1)
    epoch += 1
```

My initial thought is that it wouldn't because even though we know python random is deterministic, each successive run of `random.randrange(1,1000,1)` would still have equal weighting to be any of the 1000 possible values each epoch. Thoughts?

Comment: It wouldn't. the the seed just determine the state of the PRG ( pseudorandom number generator.) it have nothing to do with the distribution. it makes your random (or better to say pseudorandom ) number reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `random.seed` without passing any value for `a`, as you are doing, will likely cause it to [fetch state from `os.urandom()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0121f6792ab49c575e4c34f587d486e1fda85674/Modules/_randommodule.c#L275) every time.  This might be wasteful as it requests a full 19968 bits, i.e. [624 `uint32_t`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0121f6792ab49c575e4c34f587d486e1fda85674/Modules/_randommodule.c#L237), every time.  Hence, if you are only generating 100 random variates every time you reseed, `secrets.randbelow(999)+1` is probably better.

Given that output from the MT19937 can be predicted after just [624 variates](https://github.com/kmyk/mersenne-twister-predictor) then, contrary to what Mark says, this should indeed make it less predictable.  Assuming of course that your OS is making a reasonable CSRNG available to `os.urandom`,  recent versions of Linux, OSX, Windows, and most BSDs, are all fine.

Note the MT19937 is especially bad in this regard, especially given the amount of state it has, and there are a number of generators that do much better.

Comment: Interesting. Assuming an MT19937 seed continues to be used after 624 variates, though we could predict future outcomes, would the results still be "randomly" distributed? Randomly in the sense that they would show no significant skew or preference towards any set of numbers?

Comment: individual draws are uniform, it's when you look at many correlations (e.g. 10**12 draws) it starts to fall apart.  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50059/113260 has some information, namely there are some standardised tests that look at lots of different statistics from a very large number of draws from RNGs, they tend to be much more demanding than any normal monte-carlo code.  use of the MT is kind of baked into Python at this point, far too many unit tests would fail it it changed for it to be worth it

Answer (score 2):

The output of a pseudo-random number generator is determined by its transition from its current state to the next state.  A good generator will have many more bits of state than there are bits in its seed, so periodic reseeding will actually *increase* the predictability of the sequence.  I know there was a practical attack based on this in a system where the seed was unnecessarily restricted to a small number of bits.